# jQuery suggested results with form value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the need to create a "suggested results" field on a form, and I have it working from a nice jQuery script:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"language="javascript"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    "Abel Law Offices",
    "Abigail Rivamonte, Attorney at Law",
    "Abrams & Heyn"
    ];
    $( "#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" >
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: Can anyone show me how to mod this so there is a value in the form field.

Like:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" value="WHAT IS CHOSEN FROM RESULTS">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#tags').val('WHAT IS CHOSEN FROM RESULTS' );
```

here is a working example of what i think you are trying to achieve. Hope it helps

```
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      },
    select: function( event, ui ) { $('#tags').val(ui.item.value); }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ApTwD/)

Comment: technically what you did should work fine, my example is just if you want to display your selected value into a different `<input>` too

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tags').attr('value', 'WHAT IS CHOSEN FROM RESULTS' );
```

This sets the `HTML value attribute` for the input.

```
 $('#tags').val('WHAT IS CHOSEN FROM RESULTS' );
```

This sets the value of the input.

Make sure you place this code in the `DOM Ready Handler`

Comment: Check the other user's post.. You have to do that in the `select` event if you want to display the selected text